# Office 365 Deployment after Plan Change

Tags: microsoft-office-365, automated-install

We recently switched our plan from "Office 365 Mid-Sized Business" to "Business Premium".  I was initially told by MS support that the user would not notice the change, so I agreed to the plan change.  Then, the support tickets started rolling in "It says I need the Administrator Password to log into office".  As it turns out, each install needs to install a completely different Office product (Even though the Apps they use like Word, Excel, and Powerpoint are *exactly the same versions*)

There is no .MSI.  This is a "Microsoft Click-to-run" product, that we had pre-installed on our master deployment image, and now we have 100 machines that need this new product installed.  Even if I setup things using the Office Deployment Toolkit, which downloads the product locally on our deployment server, and then we run a command to install it, it still asks for the Administrator password.

Even in Microsoft's documentation that deployment states that the user must be a local administrator to install it.

So, my only option is creating a GPO and doing a silent unattended install that way?  Has anyone else run across something like this, and what did you do?

Comment: I would use the ODT and GPO if forced to.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately using GPO, or a software management platform like SCCM are the only ways around that.  If it were a smaller group I would say use something smaller like PsExec, but I wouldn't do that for more than a handful of clients. I must admit, I have not done this same jump, but I have moved users from Business Premium to Enterprise plans and never ran into this.  They had to re-authenticate thru Office, but that was it.